# Mouse flickering, 2 displays, 18.04

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors

My first screen is connected via HDMI.
My second screen (ASUS MB168B) is connected via USB 3.0.

Settings -> Displays:

When I choose 'Single Display' no mouse flickering at all.
When I choose 'Join Displays', there is mouse flickering on main screen but only at the upper part of the screen (~30% height,). 
It happens only if I move mouse cursor.

I was trying to move displays, find solutions in web, change resolutions but nothing helps here.

It's incredibly annoying. Please help.